# error service metadata is not available while trying to run WCF service

Tags: c#, wcf

My web.config for WCF service looks like below

```
<configuration>
<system.web>
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
</system.web>
<system.serviceModel>
<services>
  <service name="WcfService1.Service1">
    <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding"
      bindingConfiguration="" name="service1Endpoint" 
contract="WcfService1.IService1" />
    <endpoint address="" 
behaviorConfiguration="WcfService1.AjaxAspNetAjaxBehavior"
            binding="" contract="WcfService1.IService1" />
  </service>
</services>
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="service1Endpoint" />
  </basicHttpBinding>
  <webHttpBinding>
    <binding name="webHttpBinding" />
  </webHttpBinding>
</bindings>

<client>
  <endpoint address="http://localhost:2393/Service1.svc" 
binding="basicHttpBinding"
    bindingConfiguration="service1Endpoint" 
contract="ServiceReference1.IService1"
    name="service1Endpoint" />
  <endpoint address="http://localhost:2393/Service1.svc" 
behaviorConfiguration="WcfService1.AjaxAspNetAjaxBehavior"
            binding="webHttpBinding" contract="ServiceReference1.IService1" 
/>
</client>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior>
      <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to 
false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
      <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, 
set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid 
disclosing exception information -->
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="WcfService1.AjaxAspNetAjaxBehavior">
          <enableWebScript />
          <webHttp/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
</system.serviceModel>
<system.webServer>
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
</system.webServer>  
</configuration>
```

I have another simple aspx page created to test whether service is accessible or not. But when I am trying to run this service error displayed is **Failed to add a service. Service metadata may not be accessible. Make sure your service is running and exposing metadata.** Can anyone tell me how to resolve this error.
Thanks in advance.
My web service and contract is as below

```
namespace WcfService1
{
    [AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = 
    AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
    public class Service1 : IService1
    {
        public string GetData(int value)
        {
            return string.Format("You entered: {0}", value);
        }
    }
}
```

Contract looks like below

```
namespace WcfService1
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IService1
    {
        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, 
         ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
        string GetData(int value);
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a mex service endpoint to allow metadata to be exposed. Add a new endpoint under service node like:

```
<endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" name="MetadataEndpoint"
 contract="IMetadataExchange" />
```

Read more about Metadata Exchange Endpoint here:

http://www.wcftutorial.net/Metadata-Exchange-Endpoint.aspx